# Orbit of a matrix under conjugation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $\begin{pmatrix} p & 0 \\ 0 & q \end{pmatrix} = A\in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$ and $p\not= q$ and $p,q \not = 0$.. A group action is defined by taking the conjugation of $A$ with some other matrix in $GL_2(\mathbb R)$. To find the orbit of $A$ under this conjugation, do we just write $BAB^{-1}$ explicitly, for $B\in GL_2(\mathbb R)$? I do not see there is anything special, since $A$ is just an element of $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$ but not a subset. Is there any property or something interesting of this orbit?

Comment: On what set are you defining a group action?

Comment: sounds like the orbit is matrices similar to $A$

Comment: user398843 :  were you responding to @Servaes ?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{orb}{\operatorname{orb}}$ For instance, for any two $p\ne q\in\Bbb R$ you can say that $$\orb(\operatorname{diag}(p,q))=\{X\in \Bbb R^{2\times 2}\,:\,\det X=pq\land\operatorname{tr}X=p+q \}$$

Comment: did you mean tr $X = p + q $ ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes, thanks.